# change span content inside div with dynamic id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change the content of `span` tag inside of `div` tag with div id dynamically. I tried this code but it's not working. I think the problem with `$('#'+ids[i])`. Even I'm getting the information correctly to each id. Any suggestions please.

JavaScript:

```
var ids = ["Of0UWpK5bEo","1qYMJjTxJnM","8aAab7gxbEg","ZEd6aKdeC8g","qQcFvamzdno","yovbI8DOMpk"];
for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,statistics&id="+ ids[i] + "&key=AIzaSyDEm5wGLsWi2G3WG40re-DAJcWioQSpJ6o", function(data){
        $('#'+ids[i]).parent().find('.caption').text(data.items[0].snippet.title);
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Of0UWpK5bEo" class="status">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Of0UWpK5bEo/0.jpg" height="100px" width="100px"/>
    <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Is the AJAX coming through successfully? Define "not working".

Comment: i didn't get any errors... complete for loop working.

Comment: He expects the caption to update to the title of the video. There are no errors because jQuery finds no results for the id "#undefined" and therefore accomplishes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I found it to be the problem of variable scope.

This can be solved by using a anonymous function.

Pass the loop variable `i` to the anonymous function so that `ii` will be accessible inside the function.

Check out this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/dvce49xv/).

Here is the snippet.

```js
var ids = ["Of0UWpK5bEo", "1qYMJjTxJnM", "8aAab7gxbEg", "ZEd6aKdeC8g", "qQcFvamzdno", "yovbI8DOMpk"];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {

  (function(ii) {       // collect into 'ii' here
    $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,statistics&id=" + ids[ii] + "&key=AIzaSyDEm5wGLsWi2G3WG40re-DAJcWioQSpJ6o", function(data) {
      $('#' + ids[ii]).html(data.items[0].snippet.title);
    });
  }(i));     //pass 'i' here

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Of0UWpK5bEo" class="status">
  <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Of0UWpK5bEo/0.jpg" height="100px" width="100px" />
  <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>

</div>
```

Comment: The correct method for solving this is to use a $.each() iterator. That's why iterators exist. These answers that use an anonymous function are propagating bad habits.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is:

```
$('#'+ids[i]).find('.caption').text(...);
```

as `.caption` is the child of the ID in question itself. Hence, `.parent()` is not required.

[**A Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/ae9yfo1v/)

Also, use `var` in your loop as below. You'd create a global for no reason, otherwise.

```
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
```

As it turned out, it's due to the `async` behaviour of `$.get()` and loop being synchronous. So, your loop has already finshed running whereas you may be at your 1st or 2nd ajax request. What you need to do is scope the `id` value (based in `i`) into the ajax request, probably by creating a closure, like below.

```js
var ids = ["Of0UWpK5bEo","1qYMJjTxJnM","8aAab7gxbEg"];

for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    (function(id) {
        $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,statistics&id="+ id + "&key=AIzaSyDEm5wGLsWi2G3WG40re-DAJcWioQSpJ6o", function(data) {
            $('#' + id).find('.caption').text(id); //use data.items[0].snippet.title instead of id
        });
    }(ids[i]));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Of0UWpK5bEo" class="status">
    <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
</div>
<div id="1qYMJjTxJnM" class="status">
    <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
</div>
<div id="8aAab7gxbEg" class="status">
    <span class="caption">Text below the image</span>
</div>
```

Here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/y0uavL6L/) using fiddle echo apis.

Comment: Then, the problem is elsewhere! Did you look at the demo where it worked?

Comment: i looked into your demo. It worked if I pass index values directly like `0` ex: `ids[0]` working. but if I use like `ids[i]` not working. season?\

Comment: @Satya - See my answer. It's a scope issue. The value for "i" is not captured by the function that $.get() calls, which means it's undefined when it's used.

Answer (score -1):

This code isn't the best written, but I can explain what is going on.

Your fundamental problem is that the value for "i" is no longer what you expect it to be. By the time the results of the AJAX function have completed, it's an undefined value. The correct way to do this is with an iterator:

```
$.each(ids, function(index, id) {
    $.get("..." + id + "...", function(data) {
        $("#" + id).parent().find('.caption').text(data.items[0].snippet.title);
    });
});
```

Also, make sure your code is in a "document.ready()" block or you may not be able to find the elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(ids, function(index, id) {
        $.get("..." + id + "...", function(data) {
            $("#" + id).parent().find('.caption').text(data.items[0].snippet.title);
        });
    });
});
```

That being said, this looks like the interface should be dynamically created in Javascript. That would allow you to avoid many of the issues with matching IDs in tags and searching for sibling tags since you'd already have the reference.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/85jeaoqq/

Here's a slightly better version that dynamically creates the images and caption. It includes code to limit the text to 20 characters: https://jsfiddle.net/x7v2zt6f/

Comment: If the answer isn't working for you, please let me know what you're seeing and I'll try to help. The fiddle at the bottom should correctly update the text.

Comment: its working. Thanks.. so problem with loop? @64BitBob

Comment: More or less. It's a problem with the enclosure. The value of 'i' can be enclosed, but it increments with each call to $.get(). The calls to $.get() queue up until the loop is done. By the time the function of the $.get() calls are called, the value of "i" is 1 greater than the maximum size of the list of IDs. So you lose track of the ID you were referencing. Using an iterator captures the index and the value by passing them as values to an outer enclosed function.

Comment: I've one small problem. Some times Im getting title with more words. So what i want is, the title must be some 20 characters long. I want to skip remaining. what should I do @64BitBob

Comment: See the updated fiddle I put in. It does a substring to limit the text and puts a simple ellipsis on the end if it's over 20 characters. There are better ways to handle overflow in CSS (i.e. Set the width, set overflow to hidden, and then set the text-overflow property.), but this will do what you requested. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solves your issue.